# In Gradle, how can I output a timestamp after all tasks are complete?

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-project Gradle project, and in the root project, I have the following:

```
task timeStamp {
    doLast {
        Date now = new Date()
        println "All completed @ $now"
    }
}


allprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        it.getTasks().each {
            println "finalize set for \"$it.name\""
            if (it.name != "timeStamp") {
                it.finalizedBy(':timeStamp')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my output when running `gradlew build`, the timeStamp task is run, but it is run **before** some of the other tasks.

How can I get this time stamp to be printed after all other output? (I prefer it to directly precede `BUILD SUCCESSFUL in ##s` in the output, if that is possible)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you simply want to print timestamp at the end of the build (after last task is executed) you can implement as follows:

```
gradle.getTaskGraph().whenReady { graph ->
    graph.getAllTasks().last().doLast {
        Date now = new Date()
        println "\n ***** All completed @ $now  ***"

    }
}
```

This way, you will add an action to the last task to be executed as determined by the task execution graph computed by Gradle.

You can also use *buildFinished* hook, but the callback will be executed after the `BUILD SUCCESSFUL in ##s`  message

```
gradle.buildFinished {
    Date now = new Date()
    println "\n ***** All completed @ $now  ***"
}
```

result with command `./gradlew classes`

```
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
2 actionable tasks: 2 up-to-date

 ***** All completed @ Thu Sep 20 21:15:03 CEST 2018  ***
```

With both solutions, this callback will be executed whatever task you are executing (*gradle build*, *gradle clean*, *gradle assemble** , ..)

Comment: I validated the 'gradle.buildFinished' solution

Comment: Is there a way to invoke it even if the command fails? I want to print some extra stuff at the end even when the build fails.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat, for me the `gradle.buildFinished` approach works even if the build fails.

Answer (score 4):

you need to finalize `assembleDebug` and `assembleRelease` (or however they may be called):

```
task finalizeBuild {
    doLast {
        println(":finalizeBuild > doLast")
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'assembleDebug' || task.name == 'assembleRelease') {
        task.finalizedBy finalizeBuild
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried replacing my code with yours and the finalizebuild task was never executed.

Comment: @bnieland the tasks might have different names, `graph.getAllTasks().last()` is rather generic - and since the question did not feature any names, I could only provide an example, which generally works - while the name of the task matches (one cannot even finalizedBy/dependsOn each of the ones outputted, only most of them); for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53742392/549372