# Exclude temporary Realm files from Gradle build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, realm, build.gradle

Realm provides a database viewer called "Realm Studio" that allows users to browse the contents of their database. When the application is used to view a database, it creates several "temporary" files in the directory of the database, namely:

- A `.realm.lock` file.
- A `.realm.note` file.
- A `.realm.management` directory containing:

  - A `access_control.control.mx` file.
  - A `access_control.new_commit.cv` file.
  - A `access_control.pick_writer.cv` file.
  - A `access_control.write.mx` file.

In the context of Android, a preexisting Realm database is sometimes shipped with an application by placing the database in the `/assets` directory. Thus, when the Realm Studio is used to view this database, the aforementioned files are generated in `/assets`. For unknown reasons, this causes Gradle to hang indefinitely after the `:app:generateDebugAssets` task, apparently at the `:app:mergeDebugAssets` task.

As such, i'd like to find a way to exclude these files from the build. I've tried several methods, such as:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == 'debug') {
        variant.mergeAssets.doLast {
            delete(fileTree(dir: variant.mergeAssets.outputDir, includes: ['**/*.cv', '**/*.mx', '**/*.lock', '**/*.note']))
        }
    }
}
```

and other methods, like:

```
sourceSets.main.assets.exclude 'appData.realm.management'
sourceSets.main.assets.exclude 'appData.realm.management/access_control.control.mx'
sourceSets.main.assets.exclude 'appData.realm.management/access_control.new_commit.cv'
sourceSets.main.assets.exclude 'appData.realm.management/access_control.pick_writer.cv'
sourceSets.main.assets.exclude 'appData.realm.management/access_control.write.mx'
sourceSets.main.assets.exclude 'appData.realm.lock'
sourceSets.main.assets.exclude 'appData.realm.note'
```

to no avail.

How can one instruct Gradle to exclude these files when running a build?

**EDIT:** Small snippet of repeated output from `./gradlew -d app:mergeDebugAssets`:

```
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
[org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 8589934592, Free: 2572066816}
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 8589934592, Free: 2572066816}
[org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 1431830528, Committed: 308281344}
[org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 8589934592, Free: 2567909376}
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 8589934592, Free: 2567909376}
[org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 1431830528, Committed: 308281344}
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
[org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 8589934592, Free: 2564087808}
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 8589934592, Free: 2564087808}
[org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 1431830528, Committed: 308281344}
[org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 8589934592, Free: 2560860160}
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 8589934592, Free: 2560860160}
[org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 1431830528, Committed: 308281344}
[org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
[org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
...
```

Comment: None of the above solution works ? Any error message ?

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is that you did not delete the `.realm.management` directory.

```
android {

    ...

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name == 'debug') {
            variant.mergeAssets.doLast {
                delete(fileTree(dir: variant.mergeAssets.outputDir, includes: ['**/.realm.management', '**/*.lock', '**/*.note']))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**assets directory contents:**

[image]

**assets directory contents in apk:**

[image]

Comment: this looks almost alike the approach already presented along with the question.

Comment: @MartinZeitler: Yes, you are right. I've added `'**/.realm.management'` to be deleted.

Comment: the basic issue might be conflicting exclusive file access. I might be wrong (concerning aapt & assets), but would assume that empty directories are in general not being packaged.

Comment: @aminography I noticed that your `.realm.management` directory in the screenshot provided is not prefixed with "appData", i.e. `appData.realm.management/`. Did this solution work for you? It did not appear to resolve the issue.

Comment: @aminography almost have to up-vote this, for providing the screenshot of the assets directory, which enabled my to write that `cleanupRealm` task. else I would not have known what to write.

Answer (score 5):

guess you might be using an elder version of Realm Studio,
because according to [issue #842](https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/issues/842) and [pull request #847](https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/pull/847), those directories should meanwhile be properly cleaned up - and also report, in case not - instead of stalling. the current version [3.12](https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/releases) should have that fixed (basically any release after the 18th of June). if that should not help, the best you can do is to report it below issue #842; or file a new one issue, which is referencing issue #842. also check the file-system permissions, that the user which runs gradle is permitted to delete there; manually moving files out of the way "might" help, so the current user may re-create them and then subsequently is able to delete his own files.

both methods using gradle are workarounds - because it should not happen in the first place.

in order to obtain further information "why it stalls", run this command in the terminal:

```
./gradlew -d app:generateDebugAssets
```

respectively on Windows (the question does neither indicate the OS nor the Realm Studio version):

```
gradlew.bat -d app:generateDebugAssets
```

**edit**: one could even delete these files before each build:

```
task cleanupRealm(type: Delete) {
    delete project.projectDir.path + "/src/main/assets/.realm.management"
    delete project.projectDir.path + "/src/main/assets/appData.realm.lock"
    delete project.projectDir.path + "/src/main/assets/appData.realm.note"
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == "preDebugBuild" || task.name == "preReleaseBuild") {
        task.dependsOn cleanupRealm
    }
}
```

which changes the task graph to:

```
:app:checkDebugClasspath
:app:cleanupRealm
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild
```

Comment: I believe the description and code shown in the linked PRs has to do with Electron's renderer process and relative files containing a `renderer-` pattern, as they don't appear to be related to this issue. I am running the latest release of Realm Studio. Your suggestion to manually run the task was great, as `app:generateDebugAssets` completes successfully. `:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE` had been the last thing printed while building in Android Studio, however the real culprit appears to be `:app:mergeDebugAssets`, which repeatedly prints logs regarding the `daemon addresses registry`.

Comment: @Orbit and when you'd run `./gradlew -d :app:mergeDebugAssets`? it might be waiting to get access to a shared lock, which it does not get ...

Comment: The task hangs at 75%. I'll add a small snippet of the output that gets repeatedly logged at that point, as the full output is quite large, to the original post. Note that `./gradlew -s app:mergeDebugAssets` shows no exceptions. Also, note that without these "temporary" Realm files, this task usually completes within a few seconds.

Comment: @Orbit just added the task which creates this situation. it's not tested, because I don't have these files - but at least the task is added properly, has the correct type and I'm convinced that only the paths might vary. nevertheless it could fail, when any of these files is opened with an exclusive lock.

Comment: Your `cleanupRealm` task works great, though i've changed the call to use `delete project.projectDir.path` instead. This deletes these temporary files on every Gradle sync and every build. Any idea as to why the issue with `mergeDebugAssets` was occuring? Is there a way to simply have the build ignore these files instead of deleting them?

Comment: @Orbit ignoring them apparently did not work, therefore getting verbose might be the only option ... that it fails might be based upon illegal file-suffixes being present, when it scans the assets directory and it does not know what to do with them - or might not like the `.lock` file there (can only assume without having seen the logs). with an `ant` taks one could possibly move them elsewhere, before building - and then move them back once the build is complete; Gradle does not support this directly and cannot mix types either. this might only required, if deleting them causes other issues.

Comment: After further reading, the snippet I posted seems to be normal output. Is there a way to run this task to determine the actual issue? `./gradlew -s app:mergeDebugAssets` does not seem to complete within a reasonable amount time. Knowing why this issue is occurring would be helpful as i'd like to report it to the Realm team.

Comment: @Orbit `./gradlew -d clean build` would run the whole build, after cleaning the project. knowing where exactly the task in question gets stuck would already be better than only knowing which task gets stuck. maybe even create a simple example, which can be used to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try that :

```
android {
    aaptOptions {
        ignoreAssetsPattern "!*.cv:!*.mx:!*.lock:!*.note" 
    }
}
```

From `aapt` binary from `build-tools` folder :

```
./aapt
[...]
--ignore-assets
   Assets to be ignored. Default pattern is:
   !.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:<dir>_*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~
```

Comment: Where should the `aaptOptions` block go? Both options I tried (inside `android {}` and another in `android { buildTypes {} }`) did not appear to solve the issue.

Comment: Yes it's in the `android` block. It does not work at all ?

Comment: `ignoreAssetsPattern = ignoreAssetsPattern + "..."` would add instead of replace.

Comment: @ToYonos Correct, it does not appear to resolve the issue. Note that before setting `ignoreAssetsPattern`, `ignoreAssets` and `ignoreAssetsPattern` are both null.