# How to add a Gradle task to an Android build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I would like to add a gradle task to my Android build under Android Studio. Various on-line documentation shows clearly how to create a task, but *not* where to place it in a build.gradle file and which one of them.

**A simple, complete example would be perfect**.

BTW, I'd like to add a pre-build task to prepare some data, and maybe a post-build task to do some verification/validation.

Comment: The problem/question is, as stated, where do I insert the task in build.gradle.

Comment: "Free task slot"? Never heard of it. Please provide example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By trial-and-error and input from Martin Zeitler, I successfuly added pre- and post-build tasks to my build.gradle (app module) as shown below:

This works perfectly.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "MyPackage"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
      // My libraries here
    }

    // MY PREBUILD TASK
    task PreBuild {
        println "MY PRE-BUILD TASK"
    }

    // MY POSTBUILD TASK
    gradle.buildFinished {
        println "MY POST_BUILD TASK"
    }
}
```

Comment: once answered that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52430611/549372 ...this works, despite the op of that question somehow failed to apply the provided solution. concerning the above answer: `dependsOn` might be more solid, than defining some loose task (which nevertheless would be executed early on).

Comment: The prebuild task is incorrect that would be the equivalent as just putting code anywhere in the build.gradle file. For it to be a task the code would be in a doFirst or doLast block and be attached to another tasks in the build process. If code is being executed in the PreBuild like suggested it can really mess up your build cache and reduce performance.